# How do I use regex correctly to correctly identify a command from a client to server in an internet relay chat program in python

Tags: python, regex, verification

So I was having a bit of trouble wording my question, but essentially I am working on a client application making commands to a IRC chat server that provide certain functionality.  It was suggested we use regex to do the parsing of such commands.  The first command that needs to be completed when a client is accepted by the server is the USER command which in general will look something like this:
"USER guest 0 * :Ronnie Reagan"

The parts are the USER, followed by the username which is 1 word and I believe can contain numbers, the mode which is a numeric value from 0-9 that indicates your current mode in the chat, the star is just unused extra stuff but it has to be there, and the last part is a colon with no space before the real name.  Just as a note the manual doesn't say the real name has to be two separate names, just that it can contain spaces, so it can be any combination of letters and spaces even though its kind of weird.

This is what I came up with based on what I read about regex but have had some issues testing it.
`"USER\s[a-zA-Z0-9]\s\d\s*\s:[a-zA-z\s]"`

Here is the simple program I was using to test it based on some light tutorials I looked through

```
import re

userPattern = re.compile("USER\s[a-zA-Z0-9]\s\d\s*\s:[a-zA-z\s]")


while True:
    regexTest = input()
    isMatch = userPattern.match(regexTest)

    if bool(isMatch) == True:
        print("valid request")
    else:
        print("invalid request")
```

No matter the case I always get an invalid request and I've tried it in a few other ways too.  I can't tell if its because something is wrong with my regex or my method of testing it.

Comment: There are  websites that help you to know how your regex return looks like this one which I mostly use https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your regex:

1. `[a-zA-Z0-9]` represents a single character, you want a plus sign at the end of it so that it matches 1 or more characters: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`. Same thing about `[a-zA-z\s]`.
2. `*` in regex is a special symbol, you need to escape it if you want to match an asterisk: `\*`

So this is the fixed version of your regex that should work:
`USER\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s\d\s\*\s:[a-zA-z\s]+`

But I think it could be simplified:

1. If you don't care about what goes after a colon then you can just use `.+` there
2. Instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9]` you can just use `\w` (word matcher)

So I think this would work as well:
`USER\s\w+\s\d\s\*\s:.+`

Comment: It actually recognized it! Do you happen to know off hand if there is a more simple way to test regex than my method.  I probably shouldn't worry about it since it works.  I will have to test a few specific commands and was probably going to write either a function with a few if elifs that had each of the possible patterns it was looking for.  Also thanks so much for the quick and accurate help, i feel sad that I overlooked some of those mistakes like the + symbol.  Most of the regex challenges that I find either have to do with email or finding substrings.

Comment: You can just google 'check regex' and you'll find many online services where you can check a regex against some text. Also you could use python shell to check it in python locally. if/else checks work too